# Using SQL query in a Function and using it to output data elsewhere

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a Function which will find the assistant coach for a team within the database. (i have checked the query within phpmyadmin and it works).

```
function assistantCoach() {
   $query_assistcoach = "SELECT * FROM coach, team WHERE team.team_id = '1' and coach.team_id = '1' AND coach.team_role = 'Assistant' ";
   $assistcoach = mysql_query($conn, $query_assistcoach);
}
```

I would like to output the coaches fname and sname on Team Page the coach is linked with.

I have tried using `$assistcoach = assistantCoach();` at the top of the page and then within the page using  `<?php echo ($assistcoach['fname']) ?>`

The above is throwing a

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in \inc\functions.php:25 Stack trace: #0 \teampage.php(9): assistantCoach() #1 {main} thrown in \inc\functions.php on line 25

Line 25 is `$assistcoach = mysql_query($conn, $query_assistcoach);`  part of the function.

Answer (score -1):

You should pass `$conn` parameter to the function:

```
$assistcoach = assistantCoach($conn);
```

or connect to the database inside function.

Moreover, the function must return something to use the returned data, so you need to add in the end:

```
return($assistcoach);
```